# Android Studio 1.5.1 - Can't increase the Java heap size

Tags: java, android, android-studio, size, heap-memory

i am using Windows 7 64 bit, i tried lots of solutions from the answers that are similar to my topic, but no luck..

[image: Android Studio error message]

Comment: The instructions on how to fix the problem are in the error message. Please post your `gradle.properties` file, from your project root directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare # Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

For example, if you add the above line to a newly-created Android Studio 1.5.1 project's `gradle.properties` file, you would have:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: Adding this line 
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m`
to my gradle.properties have worked for me.